# What is the pin count difference between dimm and so-dimm ddr3 module?

Tags: ddr3

According to https://itigic.com/dimm-vs-so-dimm-characteristics-definition-and-differences/, for DDR3 module, dimm has 240 pins and so-dimm has 208 pins. What is the difference in this pin count? Number of power/ground pin difference or some other functional pin difference?

Comment: This is likely something you will have to research.  The datasheets will tell you about the *chips*, but the difference is in the *modules*.  I'd suggest searching for the spec/pinout of [DIMM and SODIMM](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DIMM+SODIMM+pinout+specification&t=opera&ia=web).

Answer (score 2):

DDR3 DIMM module data sheet example ([LINK](https://www.silicon-power.com/product/dram/tech/DDR3%20SODIMM%20Spec%20R15a.pdf)):

[image]

DDR3 SO-DIMM module data sheet example ([LINK](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/modules/unbuffered_dimm/jsf18c256_512_1gx72az.pdf)):

[image]

I tried comparing the module pins. odd number is front, even number if back. I checked only the first 26 pins.

[image]

From the picture I could see 240 pin module (DIMM) has more VSS pins.(VSS pin density) So as I expected it seems to provide more ground for signal integrity.

Comment: I count 9 \$%V_{SS}\$ pins among the first 26 pins for the 240 pin DIMM, and 10 for the 204 pin. Next argument - ?